# Signed keystore hash has a different value after upload to the play store

Tags: android, xamarin.android, keystore

In my app, developed by Xamarin, I need to check the keystore signed certificate signature. I managed to implement it to the app. But my problem is after upload the apk to the play store that signature changed. The signature which I am using to sign apk is different from the apk downloaded from the play store. Why is this happening? There are lot of codes that can get the signature from the apk. But which should I compare?

Comment: Do you try to  convert `SHA-1`  hash in hex format (as found in Play console) into `base64` hash.

Comment: yes I did. But it different from the original/uploaded apk's signature